# variadic template template parameter syntax

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have this template function (I remember seeing similar things somewhere from SO). It works on both `std::function` and `std::list` (as `Container`). But I can't really understand the syntax `template <typename, typename...> class Container`. What's in the `<` `>` seems to be a different language (compared to C/old C++). Can someone please explain it or give a good reference that explains this?

```
template <typename T, template <typename, typename...> class Container>
static bool contained(const T & x, const Container<T> & xs) {
    return std::find(xs.begin(),xs.end(),x) != xs.end();
}
```

Comment: You may find this slight modification interesting [(see here)](https://ideone.com/DhELF7). And note this will not compile with clang3.4 linking against libc++ (but will work linked libstdc++). The difference is how `std::list` is implemented. Adding a variadic parameter pack addresses this, and the output compared to the first is worth examining [(see here)](https://ideone.com/2K2u5n).

Comment: Indeed. It's good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename T, template <typename, typename...> class Container>
```

The above indicates that `Container` is a template template-parameter, which means that the `Container` type that you pass to the function template must itself be a template that takes at least one template argument - the second template argument onwards will be consumed by the parameter pack (`typename...`).

But there's a problem with your function template. As I explained, you indicate that `Container` must be a class template that takes one or more template arguments, but then the corresponding function parameter (`xs`) indicates it takes a single template argument. The reason this works with `std::list`, or `std::vector`, or `std::deque` is because their respective second template arguments, the allocator type, has a default value (`std::allocator<T>`). Your function template will not work with one of these containers if they have a non-default allocator type.

To fix it, the type of `xs` needs to accommodate the extra template arguments also.

```
template <typename T, typename... Params, 
          template <typename, typename...> class Container>
static bool contained(const T & x, const Container<T, Params...> & xs) {
    return std::find(xs.begin(),xs.end(),x) != xs.end();
}
```

---

This particular problem can, however, be solved without the use of template template parameters. Just accept any type `Container` instead of placing stipulations on it being a template. The type of the element you're searching for can be specified by using the `Container::value_type` nested type that all containers in the standard library define.

```
template <typename Container>
static bool contained(typename Container::value_type const& x, 
                      const Container& xs) {
    return std::find(xs.begin(),xs.end(),x) != xs.end();
}
```

Also, C++11 added [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) which does the same thing as your `contained()` function.